# Notification show twice on flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I'm stuck. My notification in the background show twice. But in the foreground only one notification. This is my code

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
  // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  if(
      !AwesomeStringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(message.notification?.title, considerWhiteSpaceAsEmpty: true) ||
      !AwesomeStringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(message.notification?.body, considerWhiteSpaceAsEmpty: true)
    ){
      // print('message also contained a notification: ${message.notification.body}');
      
      String imageUrl;
      imageUrl ??= message.notification.android?.imageUrl;
      imageUrl ??= message.notification.apple?.imageUrl;
      print(imageUrl);
      if(imageUrl == null){
        var id = Random().nextInt(2147483647);
        await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
          content: NotificationContent(
            id: id,
            title: message.notification.title,
            body: message.notification.body,
            color: Colors.orange,
            customSound: 'resource://raw/alert',
            notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.BigText,
            channelKey: 'basic_channel_background',
            payload: {'data':message.data['payload']}
          ),
          actionButtons: [
            NotificationActionButton(
              label: 'Lihat Selengkapnya',
              enabled: true,
              buttonType: ActionButtonType.Default,
              key: 'background',
            )
          ]
        );
      }else{
        await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
          content: NotificationContent(
            id: Random().nextInt(2147483647),
            title: message.notification.title,
            body: message.notification.body,
            bigPicture: imageUrl,
            color: Colors.orange,
            customSound: 'resource://raw/alert',
            notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.BigPicture,
            channelKey: 'basic_channel_background',
            payload: {'data':message.data['payload']}
          ),
          actionButtons: [
            NotificationActionButton(
              label: 'Lihat Selengkapnya',
              enabled: true,
              buttonType: ActionButtonType.Default,
              key: 'background',
            )
          ]
        );
      }
    }
}
// End Background Message
```

and this is my foreground code

```
// Foreground Apps
Future<void> main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  if (!kIsWeb) {
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );
    await AwesomeNotifications().initialize(
    'resource://mipmap/launcher_icon',
    [
      NotificationChannel(
          channelGroupKey: 'basic_tests',
          channelKey: 'basic_channel',
          channelName: 'My Cahaya Notification',
          channelDescription: 'Notification channel for basic tests',
          icon: 'resource://mipmap/launcher_icon',
          importance: NotificationImportance.High,
          playSound: true,
          soundSource: 'resource://raw/alert'
      ),
       NotificationChannel(
          channelGroupKey: 'basic_background',
          channelKey: 'basic_channel_background',
          channelName: 'My Cahaya Notification Background',
          channelDescription: 'Notification channel for basic tests',
          icon: 'resource://mipmap/launcher_icon',
          importance: NotificationImportance.High,
          playSound: true,
          soundSource: 'resource://raw/alert'
      ),
    ], debug: true);
    AwesomeNotifications().actionStream.listen((event) async{
      print('event received!');
      var data = event.toMap();
      if(data['buttonKeyPressed'] == "background"){
        SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        prefs.setString("Navigate", data['payload']['data']);
      }else{
        _navigateToItemForeground(data['payload']['data']);  
      }
      // do something based on event...
      // AwesomeNotifications().actionSink.close();
    });
  } 
  
   FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async{
      RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification android = message.notification?.android;
      if (notification != null && android != null && !kIsWeb) {
        if(!AwesomeStringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(message.notification?.title, considerWhiteSpaceAsEmpty: true) ||
        !AwesomeStringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(message.notification?.body, considerWhiteSpaceAsEmpty: true)){
        print("something");

        String imageUrl;
        imageUrl ??= notification.android?.imageUrl;
        imageUrl ??= notification.apple?.imageUrl;
        
        if(imageUrl == null){
          await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
            content: NotificationContent(
              id: Random().nextInt(2147483647),
              title: notification.title,
              body: notification.body,
              color: Colors.orange,
              customSound: 'resource://raw/alert',
              notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.BigText,
              channelKey: 'basic_channel',
              payload: {'data':message.data['payload']}
            ),
            actionButtons: [
              NotificationActionButton(
                label: 'Lihat Selengkapnya',
                enabled: true,
                buttonType: ActionButtonType.Default,
                key: 'test',
              )
            ]
          );
        }else{
          await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
            content: NotificationContent(
              id: Random().nextInt(2147483647),
              title: notification.title,
              body: notification.body,
              bigPicture: imageUrl,
              color: Colors.orange,
              customSound: 'resource://raw/alert',
              notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.BigPicture,
              channelKey: 'basic_channel',
              payload: {'data':message.data['payload']}
            ),
            actionButtons: [
              NotificationActionButton(
                label: 'Lihat Selengkapnya',
                enabled: true,
                buttonType: ActionButtonType.Default,
                key: 'test',
              )
            ]
          );
        }
      }
    }
  });
  runApp(MyApp());
}
// End Foreground Apps
```

and this is my screenshot
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLwYh.png)

I've tried changing the awesome notification but the result is the same. Could you help me to solve that? I hope you can help me. Thank you very much

Answer (score 11, accepted):

FCM payload

```
{
    "to":"_some_fcm_token_",
    //remove this
    "notification": {
        "title": "this is title",
        "body": "this is subtitle"
    },
    "type": "post_like",
    "data": {
        "model":{"id":"dsaflkdskfklgdkgjdksakdk"},
        "body": "this is subtitle",
        "title": "this is title",
        "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"
    },
    "priority": "normal"
}
```

The first one is manually created (locally), and the other one is automatic by Firebase.

When sending a message to your device, make sure it is a `notification` rather than `data`. The [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/notifications/) mentions that if you send data it will likely be ignored as a push notification. Only use it to send packets of data to the app instead.

Comment: 0

i've send notification not data. But my phone receive two notification while my apps not opened. When my apps opened i try send notification to my phone, My phone receive one notification

Comment: I see data in your code.        payload: {'data':message.data['payload']}

Comment: why with my payload? may i should remove that?

Comment: yes, when you use `message.data`  firebase automatically sends a push notification.

Comment: i've remove that, the result is same. My notification show twice when my apps is closed. What should i do now?

Comment: Oh sorry! my bad. Keep `message.data` as it is, but don't send `message.notification.` .  When you send notification field empty, firebase will not send push notification.

Comment: where code location "message.notification.empty" in my code?, so i can remove it

Comment: 'message.notification' is from the payload which your are sending from a backend server or from the firebase console. Just don't send notification field and it will not show the notification twice.

Comment: if i don't send notification field, how can my apps receive notification when not opened?

Comment: The notification field is mainly used to show title and subtitle of notification, you can put that in data field, If you send the notification field, the automatic firebase notification will pop up with the local awesome notification you are creating. I faced the same problem and this was the only doable solution I found.

Comment: what can i put in data field?. Can you give me an example?. I've tried to not filled notification field. But the result, my notification not showing anything

Answer (score 14):

If your Notification is sent while the App is in background, Firebase
automatically sends a Push-Notification, so you don't need to call the show Notification manually in the App.

I solved the problem like this:

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  if (message.notification != null) {
    //No need for showing Notification manually. 
    //For BackgroundMessages: Firebase automatically sends a Notification.
    //If you call the flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show()-Methode for
    //example the Notification will be displayed twice.
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: What if I want to prevent firebase from displaying the notification and want to display it myself?

Comment: @ayush did you able to get the answer?

Answer (score 0):

payload: Platform.isAndroid?
json.encode(message.data):json.encode(message.notification)

set payload data like this