# Local Notifications Plugin showing notification twice

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-local-notification

I want to play a custom notification sound only when app is in background or terminated state and if i implement onBackgroundMessage i am getting two notifications one automatic (default sound) and another manual(with custom sound)

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
      // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
      // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      print('Handling a background message ${message.messageId}');
      if (message.notification != null) {
        print(message.notification.title);
        print(message.notification.body);
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
            message.notification.hashCode,
            message.notification.title,
            message.notification.body,
            NotificationDetails(
              android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                channel.id,
                channel.name,
                channel.description,
                playSound: true,
                importance: Importance.max,
                priority: Priority.high,
                sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('sound'),
              ),
              iOS: IOSNotificationDetails()
            ));
      }
    
      // Create a notification for this
    }
```

Comment: When in  your remote message's  notification have body and title value then firebase automatic show notification in app's background and kill mode.

Comment: @khushbumovaliya Is there a way to show only one notification with sound when app is in background ?

Comment: I think this will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70921767/notification-show-twice-on-flutter/70921819